# Parse PHP getCreateAt

Tags: php, parse-platform

I am correctly retrieving my data form Parse, however when trying to call the function getCreatedAt it doesn't work.

I am correctly retrieving other info like this:

```
$obj->get(' description');
```

But when calling getCreatedAt the page doesn't work and throws this error:

```
__toString()  must not throw an exception
```

I have tried getting the timestamp like this

```
$obj->get('createdAt');
$obj->getCreatedAt();
```

But none worked.

Does anyone know what may be going on?

Comment: http://www.andrew-kirkpatrick.com/2013/04/how-to-safely-handle-php-__tostring-must-not-throw-an-exception/

Comment: I already read that, but the problem is not handling the exception but retrieving the date, it says it's NULL. Thanks anyway

Comment: The createdAt variable is a DateTime object, so the problem is probably with the initialization. It's probably being provided an incorrect value that's causing it to error out when calling it's internal toString method. I would suggest editing the getCreatedAt function and wraping the return in a try catch to grab the exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution.

I am using laravel and I was trying to print the Datetime which is not possible, as it is an object.

Instead of calling

```
 {{$obj->getCreatedAt()}}
```

You can just call

```
{{$obj->getCreatedAt()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}}
```

Thanks for your answers!